# Is ics format a good idea when dealing with several thousands events?

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

In our company we have a php application to handle our assistance tickets.

Now we are thinking to also add tickets, through that php application, into an ics (calendar) file so that appointments, meetings and to-do list are all together and, potentially, can be seen and edited even from an email client application (evolution, thunderbird ...) or a mobile phone.

Some professionals in the company have more than 2000 tickets per year, so I made a quick test: it means around 400KB ics file, and if I add even the past tickets we start with a 2MB ics file.

Not considering the mobile phones (which have bandwidth issues), will it be too large for an average email client application? Will it take too long for the php ics parser to go through the file? Have you ever had such experience?

Answer (score 1):

Any processing time with parsing any files are determined by the following factors:

1) The speed that the file can be read. Based on the hard drives (and their location) that store the file.
2) RAM for when the file is loaded into your server's memory.
3) CPU - raw processsing of data can take time, but a few MB is nothing unless there are a lot of tasks to perform during the data read (no likely).

All I can recommend is work out if it is within your budget to perform load tests with different size ics files and try and make them vary in operational task requirements. I have done this before in specific situations and not seen any issues.

Comment: yeah we have the budget for testing. What we are wondering is if it's clever to use the ics as a storage. Ics has the big advantage to be read by several apps (and devices) without any particular effort: on the other hand I'm not so sure that is a good idea to keep a single text file as a database...

Comment: talking with one of the sys-admins here in the company, we are thinking to implement Zimbra as "storage" and to use ics as a transport. This makes more sense to me. Any opinion?